# Ionic. How to use ngx-translate on string?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

In Ionic 6 I'm getting data from a central JSON service that is resolving data on an /:id page like so {{ product.title }}. The central JSON also feeds the wishlist and search facility.

central.json > page/:id
The JSON file is like this:

```
     public product: Product[] = [
{ 
  id:0,
  title: 'UK Information',
  description: 'Travel tips',
  extrainfo:'',
  ...
```

I need to use ngx-translate. In the past {{ product.title | translate }} would have pulled the data from assets/i18n/en.json and assets/i18n/fr.json.

Any ideas how I can use ngx-translate to get the dynamic text from strings on a page?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your object is in an array.

```html
<div>{{ product[0].title || translate }}</div>
```